# How can I make a view contextual filter work with a term name that may contain forward slashes?

Tags: 8, views

I need to create a view filtered by a term name that has spaces converted to dashes and non-alpha-numeric characters removed. A non-alpha-numeric is required  to match the existing/old site path structure and remove forward slashes in the term names that are causing the view term name contextual filter to fail.

For example, a node may have a term reference with the term name of *Americas/Caribbean*. The URL arg passed to the view would be *americas-caribbean*. There does not seem to be a way to use the term name context filter with sanitized term name arg.

I've spent days and got very close, but my filter view breaks if the term name contains forward slashes. I suspect other characters in the term name may cause it to fail also.

Comment: What is the relationship between the term name and the URL on your site?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm creating the URL's to the View in question from another View using the last part of the path as the context filter for the View in question.